# ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied The execution of template action 'Client_Locations' skiped the branching condition for this action isnt satisfied

Tags: selenium, automation, business-intelligence, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I designed a flow on Microsoft Power Automate, First it was working fine now I am facing trouble in getting result. I am attaching screenshots of flow so it will be easier for you to understand.
There is a Conditional Statement and if that condition satisfies as YES, I need to do two things and I am getting error for both of them.
1 -
ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied. The execution of template action 'Client_Locations' skipped: the branching condition for this action is not satisfied.
2-
ActionConditionFailed. The execution of template action 'Pass_to_EAPytools' is skipped: the 'runAfter' condition for action 'Client_Locations' is not satisfied. Expected status values 'Succeeded' and actual value 'Skipped'.

[image]
[image]
I am getting this error for both of these 2 namely Client_Locations and Pass_to_EAPytools.
Here is screenshot of error.
[image]